# Plotting a grid of lines given some points in Racket

Tags: racket

Mainly I am trying to plot some lines (like a grid) from every point that I have to it's neighbours. For example if the points are:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then there should be a line from 1 to 2 and also one from 1 to 4, similary for 5 there should be: 2-5, 4-5, 5-6 and 5-8 (basically every neighbour).

The biggest problem is that a point has two coordinates and by making a matrix (a list out of lists) and then plot it, there would be only horizontally or vertically lines (depending on how the points are generated).
What I wrote produces what I want, but I had to make two "matrices". Here's the code:

```
#lang racket
(require plot)

(define matrix (for/list ([i (in-range -270 271 60)])
                  (for/list ([j (in-range -270 271 60)])
                    (list i j))))

(define matrix2 (for/list ([i (in-range -270 271 60)])
                   (for/list ([j (in-range -270 271 60)])
                     (list j i))))

(plot (list
       (for/list ([i (in-range (length matrix))])
         (lines (list-ref matrix i)
                #:x-min -300 #:x-max 300
                #:y-min -300 #:y-max 300))
       (for/list ([i (in-range (length matrix2))])
         (lines (list-ref matrix2 i)
                #:x-min -300 #:x-max 300
                #:y-min -300 #:y-max 300))))
```

I would like to modify the points later and then plot them again, but this way I would need to make two updates and that's not efficient. Is there a way to obtain this plot, but using only one matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `plot` using a single matrix, *and* get  rid of the calls to `list-ref` like this:

```
(plot
 (list
  (for/list ([row matrix])
    (lines row
           #:x-min -300 #:x-max 300
           #:y-min -300 #:y-max 300))
  (for/list ([row matrix])
    (lines (map reverse row)
           #:x-min -300 #:x-max 300
           #:y-min -300 #:y-max 300))))
```

You seem very concerned about efficiency :). Then please remember what we told you last time: forget about `length` and `list-ref`, they're super inefficient for long lists, now you're working with singly-linked lists and you should write your algorithms in a way that they don't depend on accessing elements by index - lists are not like arrays!

If you truly need to access elements by index in Racket (which is very, very uncommon), then use vectors instead of lists.